# repeatation on output result according date insqlserver

Tags: sql-server

Concatenate values from multiple columns of 3 tables and display in one column. Date field is datetime.now my problem is if date is repeat of one table then amt2,amt3 is also repeat on same date

table1:

```
date                amt1
1-1-2016 10:44:00   111
1-1-2016 10:44:02   222    repeat date
3-4-2016 11:44:00   111
```

table2:

```
date                amt2
1-1-2016 10:44:02   101
2-2-2016 10:44:02   333
2-3-2016 10:44:02   444
```

table3:

```
date                amt3
2-2-2016 10:44:04   001
2-3-2016 10:44:02   002
3-3-2016 10:44:02   003
```

query

```
SELECT
COALESCE(t1.date, t2.date, t3.date)
, t1.amt1
, t2.amt2
, t3.amt3
FROM tb_amount t1
FULL JOIN tb_cashamt t2 ON t1.date =t2.date
FULL JOIN tb_grandtotal t3 ON t2.date = t3.date
```

output:

```
date                amt1  amt2  amt3
1-1-2016 10:44:00   111   null  NULL 
1-1-2016 10:44:02   111   101   null    data repeat on amt1(111)
2-2-2016 10:44:02   NULL  333   null
2-2-2016 10:44:04   NULL  333   001     data repeat on amt2(111)
TOTAL               ---   ---   -----
```

Desired output:

```
date        amt1          amt2          amt3
1-1-2016    111           101           NULL
2-2-2016    NULL          333           001
TOTAL       total(amt1)   total(amt1)   total(amt1)
```

I have problem with smalldatetime datatype on datecolumn. I want a result on each date and amt1,amt2,amt3 show total data on this date

Comment: That's not really a question...

Comment: You're looking for the `JOIN` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FULL JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(t1.date, t2.date, t3.date)
  , t1.amt1
  , t2.amt2
  , t3.amt3
FROM Table1 t1
FULL JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.date =t2.date 
FULL JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.date = t3.date
```

Comment: thanks for  ur reply but how i get total amt1,total amt2,total amt3 in new row of total plz tell me

Comment: @rashmi you want all the rows and a total line in the same query? Or just the total line? If both you have to do a union

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the `FULL JOIN`, also known as `FULL OUTER JOIN` as explained on [Using Outer Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx):

> To retain the nonmatching information by including nonmatching rows in the results of a join, use a full outer join. SQL Server provides the full outer join operator, FULL OUTER JOIN, which includes all rows from both tables, regardless of whether or not the other table has a matching value.

```
;
WITH    Table1      AS
(       SELECT      [Date], Amt1
        FROM    (   VALUES
                    ('2016-01-01', 111),
                    ('2016-02-02', 222),
                    ('2016-04-03', 111)
                )   AS Table1(Date, Amt1)
),      Table2      AS
(       SELECT      [Date], Amt2
        FROM    (   VALUES
                    ('2016-01-01', 101),
                    ('2016-02-02', 333),
                    ('2016-03-02', 444),
                    ('2016-03-03', 456),
                    ('2016-04-01', 101),
                    ('2016-04-03', 111)
                )   AS Table2(Date, Amt2)
),      Table3      AS
(       SELECT      [Date], Amt3
        FROM    (   VALUES
                    ('2016-02-02', 001),
                    ('2016-03-02', 002),
                    ('2016-03-03', 003),
                    ('2016-04-01', 555),
                    ('2016-04-02', 666),
                    ('2016-04-03', 777)
                )   AS Table3(Date, Amt3)
)
SELECT      ISNULL(Table1.Date, ISNULL(Table2.Date, Table3.Date)) Date, 
            Table1.Amt1, Table2.Amt2, Table3.Amt3
FROM        Table1
FULL JOIN   Table2  ON  Table1.Date = Table2.Date
FULL JOIN   Table3  ON  Table2.Date = Table3.Date
ORDER BY    ISNULL(Table1.Date, ISNULL(Table2.Date, Table3.Date))
```

Comment: thanks for  ur reply but how i get total amt1,total amt2,total amt3 in new row of total plz tell me

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one row per date, you need to group by + sum each of the tables on date level first before joining + you can use rollup for the total:

```
select coalesce(T1.Date,T2.Date,T3.Date), sum(T1.Amt1),Sum(T2.Amt2),Sum(T3.Amt3)
from
(
  select convert(date, date) as Date, sum(Amt1) as Amt1 
  from Table1 
  group by convert(date, date)
) T1 
full outer join (
  select convert(date, date) as Date, sum(Amt2) as Amt2 
  from Table2
  group by convert(date, date)
) T2 on T1.Date = T2.Date
full outer join (
  select convert(date, date) as Date, sum(Amt3) as Amt3
  from Table3
  group by convert(date, date)
) T3 on isnull(T1.Date,T2.Date) = T3.Date
group by rollup(coalesce(T1.Date,T2.Date,T3.Date))
```